# Matching light flicker rate with camera's FPS

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, frequency, camera

I know you can make [water flow backward](https://youtu.be/uENITui5_jU) or make [plants seem alive](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/xercyn/slow-dance-a-frame-that-slows-down-time) by changing the frame rate per second(FPS) of a camera.  But what would happen if the camera took a video in an environment where the light(or a LED lamp) would flicker at the same FPS of the camera.

I tried to accomplish this with an Arduino Nano, or microcontroller board, that flickered a LED at approximately 62.4999 Hz(The Threshold).

Here is the [link to the video](https://youtu.be/dkNOEvcLpdc).

Unfortunately, I can't get my threshold precise enough because the double variables in computer science get corrupted after 7 digits.

- If I positioned the camera in landscape mode and made the LED's frequency above the threshold, the camera's shutter(or the black line)will travel upward.
- If I made the LED's frequency below the threshold, the camera's shutter will travel downward.

  I know that getting the right FPS will make the shutter look still.

**The question is, what would happen if I took videos with the camera when both the camera and the light sync at the same frequency or FPS?**